# Screen-scraping a directx program with c#

Tags: c#, directx, screen-scraping

I'm looking to create a bot like program and I'm looking to use a screen-scraper to retrieve data such as health which is numerical. 
I have no idea how to accomplish this as most screen-scrapers are programmed in c++ as directx is most popular within that.

Is it possible to create a well working c# screen scraper for a directx program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of kernel mode, anything that can be done in C++ can be done in C#.

With that disclaimer out of the way please know that client-side bots don't work by actually screen-scraping and performing OCR. Instead they hook into DirectX's functions and record copies of the string text sent to DrawText, for example, or the vertices in the current world view graph and then work from there.

I've never really gotten into this area of programming so I can't give you any more specific advice, but I can tell you that you're in for an uphill struggle.

The alternative is just to use common Trainer/debugger techniques and map the memory of your target process. I assume you're targeting a game of some description, however said games often feature very heavy cheat-detection and prevention techniques and trying things out on a public server can get you banned for life (e.g. Steam's VAC).

Comment: I'm real aware of the banning and all but it's really for my personal programming interest, im just really curious how it all works. But yeah, i guess i might need to record the memory usage in that area or something.. I'll look into it thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, would you happen to know a place where i could find out more about the debugger techniques to retrieve the data? Thanks